# Where can I obtain Olivetti P6060 disk images?

Tags: emulation, disk-image

For a long time now, I've been looking for disk images from an Olivetti P6060, but so far I've found none.

The Olivetti P6060 was the second computer I wrote programs on, so making an emulator for it is something that has a lot of nostalgic value for me, but for that, I need the disk images.

So if anyone knows of any places where there are available, pointers would be appreciated.

(And since @Raffzahn has [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWkuQ.jpg) next [to his desk](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/19832/148), maybe he could help out?)

(And why does stackoverflow have no private mail system?)

Comment: :)) The 6066 beside my desk (and its 6060 sisters) haven't been fired up for some time, but I do think I have a few disks - especially from the 66, which came from a school. This includes system disks. There isn't much documentation I have, but there are quite some online resources (Most of them in Italian) . So drop me a note. Should be easy to find, as I do not hide - by now at least 4 RC.SE members had managed to contact me off RC.SE :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the image of the Olivetti p6060 system disk in imd and td0 format, tell me how can I send them to you.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to put them up on some site and add a link? Otherwise this should be just a comment.

Comment: this site https://www.ulozto.net is for free and does not require any registration (for "slow" download nor for upload)...

Comment: Internet Archive hosts disk imaghes

Comment: I put my email address temporarily in my profile description, so if you don't want to upload it somewhere, you can also mail it to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The images in Imagedisk (imd) and Teledisk (td0) format are now available [on github](https://github.com/dthierbach/olivetti-p6060), together with a tool to extract the Imagedisk format, a bit of documentation, and the three system datasets P6FWR4.1, P6FWO and P6SW.

The dataset P6FSYS which contains the filesystem visible to the P6060 seems to have been deleted on that disk.